# Добавление картинки перед <li> значением

Tags: css

Пытаюсь сделать список с картинкой. Нужно чтобы картинка примыкала к началу айтема и айтемы не налазили один на одного. Но не получается.

http://jsfiddle.net/y3tx467s/

```css
ul.mark li
{   
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
    color: white;    
 list-style: square; 
    list-style-image: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/6f07e494a0b5a976e0a2b89b213b53e1/1433263817/1182/915852/tags_box_left.png");
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mark">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y3tx467s/1/

```css
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.mark li
{   
    float: left;
    margin-left: 23px;
    background: green;
    color: white; 
    position: relative;
}

ul.mark li:before {
    content: "";
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/6f07e494a0b5a976e0a2b89b213b53e1/1433263817/1182/915852/tags_box_left.png");
}
```

```html
<ul class="mark">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

пример с использование `:before` (`:after`)

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.mark li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
}
ul.mark li:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -13px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 13px;
    background:url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/6f07e494a0b5a976e0a2b89b213b53e1/1433263817/1182/915852/tags_box_left.png");
}
```

```html
<ul class="mark">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```